# How to list all option of forms.Select in Django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Now I have a ModelForm which contains a Select field.

```
class _form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= _model
        widgets={
        'choice': forms.Select(),
        }
```

Due to some reason, I want to hide some option in select. I don't want to use js to hide the target option while find a way to hide the option before load the template.

I try to use the method below in template but failed.

```
{% for val, name in form.choice.choices %}
    {% if val != target_val %} <option value="{{val}}">{{name}}</option>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to know the correct method to achieve what I need. Or can you give me a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show de {{target_val}} value ? i think the problem is with the value of variable  target_val

Comment: @PauloPessoa {{target_val}} is passed from view. In fact, the problem is form.choice.choices show None in template. I want to get the correct grammer.

Comment: try it : form.fields.choice.choices..

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, the problem is the loop

try :

```
{% for val, name in form.fields.choice.choices %}
```

instead of:

```
{% for val, name in form.choice.choices %}
```

[builtins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#id1)

```
{% if somevar != "x" %}
  This appears if variable somevar does not equal the string "x",
  or if somevar is not found in the context
{% endif %}
```